# Pure/const functions in C

Tags: c, qualifiers

Say you have a basic variable set/get via functions in C:

```
static int MyVar=0;
void SetMyVar(int Var) { MyVar=Var; }
int GetMyVar(void) { return MyVar; }
```

Are there qualifiers you could/should be using on GetMyVar, such as `pure` or `const` ? I haven't done C++ in a long time but I think it used `const` for this. The value returned doesn't depend on the parameters, so I don't think `pure` is the correct thing to use.

Comment: C does not have a `pure` keyword.

Comment: you can have setMyVar as ```void SetMyVar (const int var)```

Comment: Plain standard C doesn't have const qualified functions or a way to mark a function as "pure".

Comment: @Siddharth They weren't asking about the setter. Anyway, that just means it can't change its local copy of `Var`, and it (or any other top-level qualifier on a function parameter) has no bearing on the signature of the function.

Comment: gcc has a `pure` in C. Must be non-standard, then.